# Tire sidewall damage in new tire. Should I change it?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

I put new tires about 2 months ago. Today I hit kerb quite hard and a chunk of rubber removed from the sidewall of the tyre. Should I change the tire or is it safe to drive in them? Here temperature gets very high - up to 52C (120F+) and I usually drive at 120km/h ( 75 mph)+ on highways. 
Car : Ford Explorer[image]!

Comment: Personally I would replace the tire as soon as possible with a chunk that size missing - but that's just me.

Comment: Are you talking about the white spot?  From the picture it really doesn't seem that bad... hard to tell really.

Comment: That is no big deal it has just cut into the underlying whitewall material and has not gotten into the structure of the sidewall. Its ugly but safe.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the only the black rubber is peeled, nearly the thickness of a balloon .

Answer (score 1):

**No, that is cosmetic damage.**

Because it is a whitewall tire the only thing scraped away is a thin layer of black rubber. If the damage went through the white layer and into metal or nylon you would know you had hit inner plys and had serious damage.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say check the pressure - make sure that (a) the tyre isn't losing pressure through the damage and (b) that at full pressure the tyre isn't deforming in any way. Otherwise it's probably OK, although slightly tricky to tell from that photo.

Comment: Thank you! The pressure is intact for the last two days and there's no apparent deformity in the tire.

Answer (score -1):

**STOP...STOP...STOP...** “Let get real!” We are talking about collision damage. Wheel vs. curb.  So, before we send this vehicle out on the road again, it needs a professional inspection. So, lets' start by jacking up the suspected wheel and checking for loose or broken parts. Tie-rod ends, wheel bearings and other related steering components, are no match for a curb, and are easily over-looked, especially when everyone is looking scuff marks on a tyre. So-Next: let’s do a real safety inspection. Remove the tyre and wheel assembly and put in on a hi-speed dynamic wheel balancer, and start looking for a bent wheel or broken belt internally inside the tyre. Finally, we need to disassemble and dismount the tyre and wheel assembly to see if there is any hidden damage inside the tyro. Last, inspect the wheel for damage such as cracks as it is a casting metal and subject to braking like glass into little shards. Not a very good experience at any speed. Finally, here is the true professionals part. Making a professional judgement on whether the tyre should be replaced or put back into service That will only come from experience, but when in doubt, lets replace the tyre. It Give everyone some piece of mind and the for safety of all... Not all, tyres are an easy fix... 35+ years in Automotive Repair... This is an easy "One" @-Highway speeds if you have to ask... Replace-It!...

Comment: Don't you think you are a bit overcautious after a common incident like hitting a curb?

Comment: So, like the old-timer who taught me “How to Work” on cars
No-Do-Overs… You just might get someone killed… Do-it-right-the-first-time. Or get a different job.

Comment: this is pretty common thing to hit a curb, the tire damage looks only cosmetic totally disagree with you in this case.